# JQM Text input used as Notes??? In an APP

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to add a notes feature in one of my apps.

ATM i'm using a simple Text Input field hidden inside a panel, my problem is when the app is closed and re-opened the notes are gone?!?

Does anyone know how to add local storage or whatevers needed to keep the notes in the app after the user closes the app?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using local storage is very simple and this question is very broad, but I will start you off.

To set an item in local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value)
```

Local storage only stores values as strings so make sure you serialize to JSON if you're looking to store an object.

To retrieve item from local storage:

```
localStorage.getItem(key)
```

This returns the string that you associated with the given key earlier.

So for example when the user leaves the app, as part of the shutdown process you could write the notes string to local storage.
Then on start-up you could check to see if there is anything stored there and retrieve it if it is.

More info on local storage [DiveIntoHTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: great thanks, this is all new to me so appreciate your help :)